# Opening csv file in Jupyter Notebok using R

Tags: r, csv, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to open a dataset saved as a csv on Jupyter Notebook.
I saved the dataset on my desktop:

```
data <- read.csv("⁨⁨Desktop/dataset1.csv")
```

I am getting the following error:

> Warning message in file(file, "rt"):
>   “cannot open file '"⁨⁨Desktop/dataset1.csv": No such file or directory”
>   Error in file(file, "rt"): cannot open the connection
>   Traceback:
>
> 1. read.csv("\u2068/Desktop\u2069/dataset1.csv")
> 2. read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
>      .     dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...)
> 3. file(file, "rt")

Can anyone understands what is going on? I am learning how to use Jupyter Notebook and I cannot find an answer online.

Comment: The `Jupyter` notebook does not know where your Desktop is. Try uploading the file to the `Jupyter` notebook environment.

Comment: Provide the full directory like "C:/Users/.../Desktop/dataset1.csv"

Comment: Please accept answers to your questions if one was suitable, or explain why not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload the file as in the red highlight in this screenshot. The uploaded file will then be local to any notebooks created in the same folder.

[image]

So your code would be

```
read.csv("yourfile.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to read file using relative path:

setwd() : set working directory

getwd() : get working directory

if you put your file in desktop,it will be like this:

```
    setwd("C:/User/user/dektop") 
    a <- read.csv("filename.csv")
```